# Wordwrap with Monodevelop.texteditor

Tags: monodevelop, word-wrap

Does Monodevelop.texteditor support word wrap? Monodevelop itself doesn't seem to have a way to enable wordwrap, is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't currently support word wrapping.

Comment: @Plot, seems that it's still not possible in version 5.7.

Comment: So.. How much time do we have to wait for them to implement this insignificant (yet comfortable) feature?

Comment: The year is 2020... Is it possible for someone to write a plugin for MonoDevelop to impliment this?